# using deep linking in android with adds

Tags: android, deep-linking

How to open specific page of another app on clicking add in app in android ? I am creating an android app in which add are showing .when clicking on that add it opens the play store. But i want to open specific page of that app using deeplinking. e.g am getting snapdeal offers add in my application when i click on that add it open the specific page of snapdeal.How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the package name of the app you want to open in playstore:

```
String appPackageName = "package_xy"; // eg. com.twitter.android

try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //if playstore app not installed
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

So you probably would need your advertisement to send the package name of their app with it. Or just an url to open (maybe send the playstore browser link in the catch above if its an app, so you could detect the play.google.com part and replace accordingly or just open the plain website if its not a playstore url).

You asked what happens if the app is already installed: Still the same. You should check for it first:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
String appPackageName = "package_xy"; 

try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackageName);
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
{
    //open playstore instead
}
```

So this is only one of many ways. If the app is not found on the device, the try will fail and catch is executed. If it is found it will be opened.
In the case of twitter I even could open it with a deeplink like this:
`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://status?status_id="+id));`

For some things like PDF there are ways to open the applicationpicker, but I don't think thats what you need in this case.
You should be fine if you use the above code. Just put the first snippet in the catch of the second one and you should be fine.

Comment: wha happen if the specific app is already installed in phone.